# Faithfully flatness of $A\subseteq B$ implies $aB\cap A = aA$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

When $A\subseteq B$ is faithfully flat, why does $aB\cap A = aA$ hold, where $a\in A$?

Comment: Please explain which kind of things your $A$ and $B$ are, and preferably also what "faithfully flat" means.

Answer (score 0):

Since the quotient $B/A$ is flat, $M \to B \otimes_A M$ is injective for every $A$-module $M$. For $M = A/I$ this gives $IB \cap A = I$.